# Unit testing angular with switch map and forkjoin

Tags: angular, switch-statement, intervals

I have tried the unit testing for a function which is used by switch mapa and forkjoin..it is not convering the statement for switch map..any help is appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6F4q.jpg)

Seems like interval is causing the issue,is there any way to check this interval

Comment: please include code directly and not as an image

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync you basically have to advance time manually in unit test in order for timed functions such as interval to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.